# Is there a way to consolidate event actions from a custom search page?

Tags: google-analytics

We operate knowledge widget on our website where users can search for keywords and get knowledge about a wide array of topics. We track these searches in Google Analytics via an *event category*, which makes the search queries *event actions*.

Not surprisingly, we face two issues:

1. Users spell the same query in different ways (e.g. typos, singular/plural, with/without article, etc.)
2. Users sometimes formulate search phrases as a single word, and sometimes as a complete or partial sentence (e.g. "item", "what about item", "give me details about item", etc.)

Is there a way to consolidate these very different *event actions* into one? Right now, we have results like this:

*item: 20 searches

itme: 3 searches

about item: 8 searches

the item: 9 searches

items: 12 searches

give me details about item: 1 search

what about item: 1 search

etc.*

The goal is to just have:

*item: 54 searches*

Is there a way (within or separate from GA) to make this happen?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **search-and-replace** filters to fine-tune the data in your Analytics views (not for historical data): https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en

Anyway, you can filter in the report filter with a regex (i.e `item|itme|etc...`), to combine all the cases, and read the value of the first row or the total.

You can also export the data to an Excel/Spreadsheet and do this work separately.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this would require to add every possible variant of a search phrase manually?

Comment: Yes, I don't see how it is possible otherwise to make Google Analytics understand by itself what you want to associate a wrong search term... probably in the future with artificial intelligence, but it will still be something interpretable.